# GitLab Code Quality always display Code Quality hasn't changed

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

The version of Gitlab I'm currently using is the community version 15.11, and integrating a custom Code Quality tool following the instructions given in the official manual currently generates reports in the following format.

```
[
    {
        "description": "global macro 'MAJOR_VERSION' not referenced [MISRA 2012 Rule 2.5, advisory]",
        "fingerprint": "c4288d3b-160e-4c22-b614-5a9a38034e4d",
        "severity": "minor",
        "location": {
            "path": "XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX.h",
            "lines": {
                "begin": 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding .yml is

```
code_quality.
    stage: test
    script: 
      - codelint.bat
    tags: 
      - windowsserver
    only:
      - api
      - merge_requests  
    artifacts.
      reports: 
        codequality: XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/result/Report.json
      paths:
        - XXXX/XXXX/result/
```

But it keeps showing up in the UI after the merge request is raised,

> Code Quality hasn’t changed.

so please tell me what's going on, this is the first time I've used the Code Quality feature in my project!

Comment: Have you generated a report using a pipeline on the _default branch_ of the project?